# Azure WebJob no longer picking up Entity Framework connection string setting in portal

Tags: entity-framework, azure, connection-string, azure-webjobs

I've had an Azure WebJob running for at least two years without any problems. The app.config contains the following...

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="UniversalModelEntities" connectionString="dummy - the actual connection string is specified in the portal but for some reason we need this element here" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />  
</connectionStrings>
```

And in the portal's *Application Settings* I have...

[image]

This has run without any problems... until this morning when I found the error

> The connection string 'UniversalModelEntities' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute."

Everything I've found regarding Entity Framework connection strings in the Azure portal says that I should set that drop-down to `Custom`.

So what's the problem?

Furthermore, I've found that even if declare the full connection string in the app.config, I still get the same error message, which suggests that the problem lies in the portal's setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by setting the drop-down option for the connection string to `SQLAzure`...

[image]

...which obviously results in an error, then changing it back to `Custom`...

[image]

Now the WebJob picks up the connection string correctly.

Comment: Important: Don't forget to replace &quote; for '